# Pearson correlation in python data.corr()

Tags: python-3.x, cross-correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a matrix with the following shape `(20, 17)` with rows being the time and columns the number of variables.

When i compute the correlation matrix using `data.corr()` naturally i get a `(17 , 17)` matrix.

My questions:

Is there a way to normalise the variables `directly` within the `.corr()` function? (i know i can do that before hand and then apply the function)

My correlation matrix is large and I have trouble viewing everything in one go (i have to scroll down to do the necessary comparison). Is there a way to present the results in a concise way (like a heat map) where i can easily spot the highest from the lowest correlation?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use matplotlib's `imshow()` to see a heatmap of any matrix.

Also, consider using pandas dataframes, this way you could sort by correlation strength and keep the labels of each row and col.

Comment: i am sharing the code in case there is an interest               
 `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
sb.heatmap(matrix)
plt.show()`